# Image has a big margin-left that was not set

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists, margin

I'm trying to create a list with images, side by side, each one has its link and an effect on hover. Everything works fine, except the images create a 142px left margin out of somewhere.

The margin is 0 (declared multiple times as `margin: 0`) and, using Firebug (Firefox debug tool) it says the images have a 142px left margin.

The code is as follows (shortened, of course):

```
<div id="">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""><img src="" /><img class="bloom" src="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="" /><img class="bloom" src="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="" /><img class="bloom" src="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
# {
    height: 185px;
    padding: 16px 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

# ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 951px;
}

# li {
    background: black; /*just to verify if the margin was on the LI or IMG*/
    float: left;
    height: 185px;
    margin: 0 16px;
    width: 285px;
}

# img {
    position: absolute;
}

# img.bloom {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The "bloom" image is part of the hover effect.
As you can see, NOWHERE was "margin left" set, neither here nor anywhere in the css. You can see it in the link: http://ranierialthoff.com.br/elite/ the images just before the footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see `text-align:center` in your `#unidades li` element. It will make `img` center.

You can change it to `left` to fix your problem.

If you want to centralize them. Just remove `position:absolute` in `#unidades img` and keep `text-align:center` still.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. How can I "centralize" them otherwise?

Comment: Both images have to be at the exact same place (one over another), so I can't remove it or they get aligned side-by-side. Doesn't matter, I got a workaround by setting fixed size for the images, so I know the exact width :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a left margin, it's the position of the image. Your problem is that you are absolutely positioning the images without telling the browser *where* to put them. You need to add `top: 0; left: 0;` or similar to your `#unidades img` styles.

Comment: Well, I discovered the problem was the `text-align: center;`. The images were being positioned with its left side on the center of the li, instead of just centralizing. But nice answer :D